# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException Hibernate Java

Tags: java, hibernate

Following is my code. I am using one bean hibernate entity class which represents table VendorPrioritizedData and the class is as follows.

```
package com.mt.indexes.hibernateEntities;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "vendor_prioritized_data")
public class VendorPrioritizedData implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sc_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sc_id_seq", sequenceName = "vendor_prioritized_data_id_seq1", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "record_id")
    private String recordId;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private LocalDate startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private LocalDate endDate;

    @Column(name = "entity_id")
    private String entityId;

    @Column(name = "attribute_code")
    private String attributeCode;

    @Column(name = "attribute_type")
    private String attributeType;

    @Column(name = "val")
    private String val;

    @Column(name = "source")
    private String source;
    
 
}
```

Then I am using this class in one of my method in the code and that is as follows.

List fsFFDB = refDataRdsSession.createNativeQuery(DBQueries.GET_FTOS_FROM_BOB)
.setParameter("investmentId", investmentId)
.list();

```
        List<LocalDate> tosstartDateList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (VendorPrioritizedData tosStartDate : fsFFDB) {
            tosstartDateList.add(tosStartDate.getStartDate());
        }
```

I am getting the following error now which is landing me in confusion.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class com.mst.indexes.hibernateEntities.VendorPrioritizedData ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.mst.indexes.hibernateEntities.VendorPrioritizedData is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I am getting this error on line 'for (VendorPrioritizedData tosStartDate : fsFFDB) {'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in your code:

```
List fsFFDB = refDataRdsSession.createNativeQuery(DBQueries.GET_FTOS_FROM_BOB, VendorPrioritizedData.class).setParameter("investmentId", investmentId).list();
```

You have to tell the result, which class the objects should be passed in.